# Set Cookie for Proactive Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, popup

I am trying to create a popup that will prompt a website visitor to speak with support staff. Once the user has seen the popup, however, I want to make sure that they do not get that proactive popup again when they go to other parts of the website.

To do this I was trying to create a cookie which will expire in 1 day, and have the popup hidden if the script can retrieve that cookie from the visitor. This is the code I have so far. The popup works fine, but I cannot get it to see the cookie and hide the popup when I visit the page a second time.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>dialogBox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dialogbox.css">
</head>
<body style="background:#eee">
    <div id="dialog"></div>
    <div id="message"></div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dialogBox.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (messageCookie.value==null) {
        $(function(){ 
            var dialog = (function(){
                $('#dialog').dialogBox({
                    hasClose: true,
                    effect: 'fade',
                    hasBtn: true,
                    confirmValue: 'Chat Now',
                    hasMask: true,
                    confirm:function(){
                        //Put website alive chat here
                        window.open('https://a4.websitealive.com/840/visitor/window/?code_id=355&dl='+escape(document.location.href),'wsa_840_306','height=200,width=200')
                    },
                    title: '',
                    content: 'Click the button below to chat with an expert',
                    callback: function(){
                        console.log('loading over')
                        setCookie(messageCookie, 1);
                    }
                })
            })
            setTimeout(dialog, 1000);
        })
        }
        else {
            //do nothing
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setCookie(key, value) {
            var expires = new Date();
            expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```